# USRP2 Overflow problem

Tags: gnuradio, system-generator, usrp

I am trying to capture the wlan samples from gnuradio-companion. I have configured the  USRP Soource with the following :

- Ch0 Gain = 50dB
- device addr : 192.168.10.3
- Center Frequency :   2.437GHz
- Sample Rate : 11M

But , when I execute the model, I receive the Overflow message at the console. Any hints whether the configuration is proper for collecting the samples ?

Here is the attached model: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

An 'overflow' indicates that your computer is receiving data faster than it is capable of processing it.

I realize this is an old question, but for anyone else that looks at this question hoping to find something useful, remember that your computer must process the samples.  Here, you are dumping the samples into two graphical sinks, and also writing to your hard disk at 11 MSps (11e6 * 32bits = 352 MBits / sec).

If you are on a machine that can't keep up with that, the overflows would be expected!

Answer (score 1):

You do not state if you run as root or not, but for me running as root solved the problem for me. Running as root gives you more privelegies and so you can use more features of the processor.